# What is the ideal format to store large results generated by R?

Tags: r, bigdata, mclapply

I simulate reasonably sized datasets (10-20mb) through a large number of parameter combinations (20-40k). Each dataset x parameter set is pushed through `mclapply` and the result is a `list` where each item contains output data (as list item 1) and parameters used to generate that result as list item 2 (where each element of that list is a parameter).

I just ran through a 81K list (but had to run them in 30k chunks) and the resulting lists are around 700 mb each. I've stored them as `.rdata` files but will probably resave them to `.Rda`. But each file takes forever to be read into `R`. Is there a best practice here, especially for long-term storage?

Ideally I would keep everything in one list but `mclapply` throws an error about not being able to serialize vectors, AND a job this large would take forever on the cluster (split 3 ways, it took 3 hours/job). But having several results files `results1a.rdata`, `results2b.rdata`, `results3c.rdata` also seems inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have a couple of different questions there -- I'd recommend asking about optimizing your list format in a separate question.

Regarding reading/writing R data to disk, however, I'm not sure that there's a better way than Rda files in terms of efficiency. *However*, I have found that the level of compression can have a real effect on the amount of time it takes to read/write these files depending on the computational setup. I've typically found that you get the best performance using no compression (`save(x,file="y.Rda", compress=FALSE)`).

As a backup plan, you can try leaving the compression on, but varying the level of compression, as well.

Comment: Another option is `saveRDS` which will allow you to restore the object with a different name.